# How to implement Time To Live (TTL) for a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to have a topic deleted after some predefined time of inactivity.

To give you some context, there's a microservice that has many replicas, and each replica has its own topic to communicate, identified by its replica Id (e.g. topic_microservice-name_<random_id>).
If for any reason, a replica crashes, K8s will start another Pod, with a completely different replica Id, therefore the previous topic will not be used anymore. For this reason, after some time there could be many useless topics.

Does kafka have a built-in Time To Live for the whole topic?

Another idea I have is to have a [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) Job iterating all topics somehow getting the last modified/written date and checking if the TTL expired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to give a topic a TTL, where once the TTL expires Kafka automatically deletes the topic.

One can configure retention on the topic level (`retention.ms` - how long messages should be retained for this topic or `retention.bytes` - the amount of messages to retain in bytes). With this, you could have a separate service leveraging the `AdminClient` to execute scheduled operations on your topics. The logic could simply be iterating over the topics, filtering out the active topics, and deleting each topic that has been inactive long enough for the retention strategy to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just to make sure (I'm new to Kafka), can you elaborate further? How would I know (programmatically) that the retention strategy has taken effect?

Comment: TBH it depends on how the system is setup.  If you have a list of all the active pod replica id's that the AdminClient could access, there's a method for retrieving all the topics via List. With that, filter out the topics you don't want to delete && the topics that are being processed by an active pod.  With the topics you have left, you can iterate and delete (via AdminClient).

Comment: it's also possible to have the AdminClient iterate over all topics->get their descriptions/partitions->get offsets for records written on or immediately after a specified time / or just get offsets. If the offset is at 0, this could mean the topic was just created or the records for the topic have been deleted completely (more likely). I would delete the ones I find using an approach like that.   There's a book confluent gives for free - Kafka The Definitive Guide v2 that covers programatic admin operations (chapter 5), it does a great job explaining AdminClient as well as Kafka itself

Comment: Again, it's hard to say the most efficient solution without knowing the full context. Topics are broken into partitions, and partitions can have multiple replicas. If the topics you're referencing has multiple partitions, and a high number of topics are always in the cluster, would not be wise to do such hefty admin operations regularly. Hopefully the least I've done with these comments is shed light on what the AdminClient can do for you in terms of automating Admin operations through code

Comment: ^^ my second comment wouldn't totally be true if there was more than one partition. You'd have to ensure all partitions for the topic have reached a state where you can confidently assume no one will be using it anymore and the topic as a whole should be deleted

Comment: Once again, thanks for the tips. Your second comment seems one useful approach, checking if the offset is at 0. Makes sense because, with the retention time strategy enabled, Kafka will delete all messages and the offset will be at 0.

Comment: Happy to help! I believe @JavaTechnical hit a key note on design (coming up with solutions can be done, but maybe the initial problem can be eliminated with some  redesign)  and has a more technical version of solutions above dealing with Kubernetes.

Answer (score 3):

The original question as to whether kafka topic actually has a TTL has already been answered (which is *NO* as of writing this answer).
This answer deals with several ways to handle deletion of topics w.r.t your scenario.

1. **Write a container `preStop` [hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/)**

   Where you can execute the topic's deletion code upon a pod termination. This could be simple approach.
   The hook implementations include `exec` command (or) a `HTTP` call.

   You can for example, include a small wrapper script on top of `kafka-topics.sh` (or) a simple python script that could connect to the broker and delete the topic.

   You might also want to make a note of `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` and increase it accordingly if your topic deletion script takes longer than this value.

---

2. **Get notified using Kubernetes Watch APIs**

   You may need to write a client that listens to the events and use the `AdminClient` to delete the topics corresponding to the terminated pod. This typically needs to be separated from the terminated pod.

---

3. **Find out what topics needs to be deleted by getting list of active pods.**

   1. Retrieve the `pod replicas` available in the Kubernetes cluster using Kubernetes API.
   2. Iterate over all the topics and delete those which do not conform to the above retrieved list.

***P.S:***

Note that the deletion of topics is an administrative task and it is typically done *manually* after some verification checks.

Creation of a lot of topics isn't recommended as maintenance would be difficult. If your applications are creating a lot of topics, for eg, as many as the number of workload instances running, then it might be the time to rethink your application design.